# Android Exception When App Is Idle

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an exception that is thrown after the app has been sitting idle for awhile.  It seems to always happen when my app is trying to reference my singleton typeface class.

My singleton class (TypefaceSingleton.java) is used to reference the Roboto fonts from a single source.  This is a scaled down version of the actual file.  I have labeled the line from the stack trace.

---

### TypefaceSingleton.java class

```
package com.steve.demo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.View;

public class TypefaceSingleton {

    private static Context mContext;
    public static void initialize(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }


    private static  Typeface robotoCondensedBoldItalic;
    public static Typeface getRobotoCondensedBoldItalic() {
        if (robotoCondensedBoldItalic == null) {
            // (TypefaceSingleton.java:111) is below
            robotoCondensedBoldItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto/RobotoCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf");  
        }
        return robotoCondensedBoldItalic;
    }

    private static TypefaceSingleton mInstance;
    public static TypefaceSingleton getInstance() {
        if (mContext == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This class must be initialized before");
        }

        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new TypefaceSingleton();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private TypefaceSingleton() {
        // Todo here
    }

}
```

I initialize the singleton class **only once**.  I have a splashscreen activity that performs the initialization.

---

### SplashScreenActivity.java

```
// Perform Initialization
TypefaceSingleton.initialize(mContext.getApplicationContext());
TypefaceSingleton.getInstance();
```

The exception thrown is indicating a null pointer reference to TypefaceSingleton.getRobotoCondensedBoldItalic.

---

### From the Developers Console

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.steve.demo/com.steve.demo.RoutesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2334)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.steve.demo.TypefaceSingleton.getRobotoCondensedBoldItalic(TypefaceSingleton.java:111)
at com.steve.demo.RoutesActivity.setCustomActionBarTitle(RoutesActivity.java:130)
at com.steve.demo.RoutesActivity.onCreate(RoutesActivity.java:86)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
... 11 more
```

I am sure the issue have to with the java is handling memory (ie, garbage collection?) but I not sure how to resolve.

Thanks in advance.

Steve

Comment: Because it gets nulled, during the system resource harvesting. You have to re-instance your Class each time the app comes to front (i.e.: the last Activity gets re-created).

Comment: TypefaceSingleton aSingleton = new TypefaceSingleton(); then call aSingleton.initialize()

Comment: Unrelated to your question: Make it `getInstance(Context)` and `mContext = context.getApplicationContext()` in there so client code cannot use that class  wrong. You currently require that client code uses the class in a very specific way and order.

Comment: @DerGolem - I had misunderstanding the Singleton class and memory management.  I expected it to be in memory since I instantiated once.  I partially thought this since my app was still available in the app history (eg, holding down the Home button and seeing my app), that my singleton class was still alive.  I guess another way to approach this is to put typeface initialization call into a base class and have my activity inherit from there.  Then it is in one place.

Comment: When your app goes in background, Android starts reclaiming resources. It's like a tax agent. No mercy. So, you have to reinitialize all the classes (and not only - even images, sounds or whatever!) on each Activity resurrection.